# R stargazer, lme4 and lmerTest incompatibility

Tags: r, latex, lme4, stargazer

R novice here. I'm having issues working with `lmerTest` and `stargazer`. I was following the tutorial here to get `stargazer` to work with `lme4` in R.

http://svmiller.com/blog/2015/02/quasi-automating-the-inclusion-of-random-effects-in-rs-stargazer-package/

I ran this example with no issues.

```
library(lme4)
library(stargazer)
data(cake)
summary(M1 <- lmer(angle ~ temp + (1 | replicate) + (1|recipe:replicate), cake, REML= FALSE))
summary(M2 <- lmer(angle ~ factor(temperature) + (1 | replicate) + (1|recipe:replicate), cake, REML= FALSE))
anova(M1,M2)
stargazer(M1, M2, style="ajps", title="An Illustrative Model Using Cake Data", dep.var.labels.include = FALSE, 
          covariate.labels=c( "Temperature (Continuous)", "Temperature (Factor $<$ 185)", "Temperature (Factor $<$ 195)", "Temperature (Factor $<$ 205)", "Temperature (Factor $<$ 215)", "Temperature (Factor $<$ 225)")
)
```

While that works, if I include the `lmerTest` package, `stargazer` no longer works.

```
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)
library(stargazer)
data(cake)
summary(M1 <- lmer(angle ~ temp + (1 | replicate) + (1|recipe:replicate), cake, REML= FALSE))
summary(M2 <- lmer(angle ~ factor(temperature) + (1 | replicate) + (1|recipe:replicate), cake, REML= FALSE))
anova(M1,M2)
stargazer(M1, M2, style="ajps", title="An Illustrative Model Using Cake Data", dep.var.labels.include = FALSE, 
          covariate.labels=c( "Temperature (Continuous)", "Temperature (Factor $<$ 185)", "Temperature (Factor $<$ 195)", "Temperature (Factor $<$ 205)", "Temperature (Factor $<$ 215)", "Temperature (Factor $<$ 225)")
)

Error in objects[[i]]$zelig.call : 
  $ operator not defined for this S4 class
```

I really would like to use `stargazer` but my experiments require the use of  `merModLmerTest` objects, which `stargazer` doesn't support. Does someone know of a workaround? How difficult would it be to cast a `merModLmerTest` object into a `lmerMod` object that would be compatible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is an easy fix. Convert the output of the `lmerTest` (which is in class `merModLmerTest`) to the `lmerMod` class. This will be compatible with stargazer.

```
class(model) <- "lmerMod"
```

Comment: For anyone surfing the web, this does work. Nicely done.

Comment: This also helps if you are getting `Error: $ operator not defined for this S4 class` if you are giving stargaze model from lmer. Complete working code: `lmm.data <- read.table("http://bayes.acs.unt.edu:8083/BayesContent/class/Jon/R_SC/Module9/lmm.data.txt", header=TRUE, sep=",", na.strings="NA", dec=".", strip.white=TRUE)

MLexamp.6 <- lmer(extro ~ open + agree + social + (1|school), data=lmm.data)

class(MLexamp.6) <- "lmerMod"
stargazer(MLexamp.6, type = "text")`

Answer (score 9):

Just looking through that code, I think it's a `stargazer` issue.  `stargazer` can read objects of class `lmerMod`, not `merModLmerTest`. Since that hack the author describes requires the `stargazer` package in order to include random effects via `stargazer`, I think you're stuck.

If you really need `lmerTest` for your job (looks like for the `anova` function, right?), I'd recommend the following.

1. Run your model and get your anova. Look it as you see fit.
2. Run your models again, but specify you want `lme4` estimating the models. You do this by typing `lme4::lmer(y + x1, Data)`. Since you loaded the `lmerTest` package after `lme4`, `lmerTest` actually becomes the default package for running `lmer` functions. This is why your object became a class that `stargazer` couldn't read. At the end of the day, it's the same model, just stored differently.
3. Finally, use `xtable` to create the anova results in LaTeX, if that's what you were wanting.

This revised code should help you.

```
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)
library(stargazer)
library(xtable)
data(cake)

# Get the table first.
summary(M1 <- lme4::lmer(angle ~ temp + (1 | replicate) + (1|recipe:replicate), cake, REML= FALSE))
summary(M2 <- lme4::lmer(angle ~ factor(temperature) + (1 | replicate) + (1|recipe:replicate), cake, REML= FALSE))

stargazer(M1, M2, style="ajps", title="An Illustrative Model Using Cake Data", dep.var.labels.include = FALSE, 
      covariate.labels=c( "Temperature (Continuous)", "Temperature (Factor $<$ 185)", "Temperature (Factor $<$ 195)", "Temperature (Factor $<$ 205)", "Temperature (Factor $<$ 215)", "Temperature (Factor $<$ 225)")
)

# now for lmerTest
summary(M1a <- lmer(angle ~ temp + (1 | replicate) + (1|recipe:replicate), cake, REML= FALSE))
summary(M2a <- lmer(angle ~ factor(temperature) + (1 | replicate) + (1|recipe:replicate), cake, REML= FALSE))
anovadf <- data.frame(anova(M1a,M2a))
xtable(anovadf)
```