# stargazer lme4 incompatible

Tags: error-handling, regression, lme4, stargazer

I am using lmer from the lme4 package and lmerTest. My regression looks as follows:

```
r1 <- lmer(a ~ b + c + as.factor(d) + (1 | e), data = df)
```

I would like to use stargazer and used this code:

```
stargazer(r1, type = "text")
```

However, it doesn't work. R returns this error:

```
Error in objects[[i]]$zelig.call : $ operator not defined for this S4 class
```

Actually I don't know what the problem is, I already checked if there are packages which are incompatible with each other but that does not seem to be the case. Does anyone have an idea what the problem might be or if there is an alternative to stargazer when using lmer?

Comment: Would you please post a small data subset that will reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 3):

This is a compatibility issue between `lmerTest` and `stargazer`. If `lmerTest` is loaded into R along with `lme4`, then it changes the class of the model objects from `"lmerMod"` to `"lmerModLmerTest"`. Only the former is compatible with `stargazer`.

The simplest fix is to avoid loading `lmerTest` in the first place, which worked for me.

The real fix (from [R stargazer, lme4 and lmerTest incompatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31319030/r-stargazer-lme4-and-lmertest-incompatibility/31439451)) is to change the class of your model object back to the compatible one:

```
class(r1) <- "lmerMod"
```